# Trying to secure files from being accessed in the first place

Tags: php, jquery, html

```
function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
    Transition();
    var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
        new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
        new XMLHttpRequest;

    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
            request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
            callback(request, request.status);
        }
    };

    request.open('GET', url, true);
    request.send(null);
    Transition();
}

function Transition() {
    var xmlhttp = window.ActiveXObject ?
        new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
        new XMLHttpRequest;

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
            callback(xmlhttp, xmlhttp.status);
        }
    };

    xmlhttp.open("GET", "transition.php", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Ah yes, I'm trying to use jQuery and turn on a session variable and after performing another jQuery function turn that session variable off using the above method. `transition.php` is the file that turns the variable on and off and the other jQuery function `downloadUrl` simply downloads XML format file.

In summary I have a `.php` file that needs to stay open just long enough to access the data in it, then immediately close.

Comment: Does my answer help?

Comment: Potentially as Ive not yet taken it into practice. Im basically looking to have a side file of php code that does processing of some sorts.. that i turn only on when accessing with site. If a user tries to access it. They fail everytime. Will your code in theory work for this?

Comment: In theory, yes!  My answer fixes your code to do what you describe  - fire AJAX requests in sequence.  Check the JSFiddle to see it working.

Comment: Thank you Don't Panic as it worked! Im quite new to jquery and ajax as of lately. Thank you!

Comment: How do I accept? @_@ Im new to website

Comment: The link I included describes how to both accept and upvote.  Thanks!

Comment: Thank you as well :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:** corrected some wording around `onreadystatechange` and `readyState`.

Your trick of turning things on or off is a neat idea, though I am not sure if it will work or is safe.  In any case, the immediate problem with the code you've shown is that it does not take into account the fact that you are using *asynchronous* requests.

Your code runs in the order it is written, but async requests don't hold up execution, so the 2nd `XMLHttpRequest` to `url` is firing almost immediately, and long before the first `Transition()` has completed.

If you need things to happen sequentially, you need to call subsequent steps from the request `onreadystatechange` event handler, which is fired when the state of the request changes.  The code already tests for `readyState 4`, which means the request is done.  So code called there runs *after* the request has completed.

I am not sure what some of your code is doing, maybe it is copied here out of context (eg what is your `callback`, and `doNothing`?).

[Here's a working JSFiddle based on your code](https://jsfiddle.net/dont_panic/fj6ekns1/), using a dummy URL for all 3 requests.  I've included a bunch of logging, open your dev console to see the order things fire and run and complete.

The idea is to pass a callback to the first `Transition`, which will be fired after that request completes:

```
function downloadUrl() {
    Transition(foo);
}
```

`Transition` takes the callback as a parameter, and fires it when complete:

```
function Transition(callback) {

    // ... your code ... 

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
            if (callback) {
                callback();
            }
        }
    };

    // ... your code

}
```

Here `foo()` is a function which does the actual download of `url`, basically everything you have in `downloadUrl()` but without the calls to `Transition`.

When `foo()` is done, you need to call `Transition` again, but this time we don't want to fire anything when it is done, so we pass `false`, which `Transition` will test and skip trying to execute.

I wrote this quickly and it feels a bit clunky, you could probably massage this a bit to get it neater, but it demonstrates the basic idea of using the event handlers to do things sequentially with async requests.